# JavaScript removes Title on WordPress Website

Tags: javascript, wordpress, title

So I stumbled onto this issue and it is a big one, it appears that there is some JavaScript that is removing the title from my webpages.

https://fyxtrpg.com/

When the page loads I see the title in the tab for a moment then it disappears.

If I look at the page source it is still there. However, if I inspect it with dev tools it is blank. What could be causing this? How do I track this down? This is a huge issue with SEO.

Thanks for your help!

Clarification: 
To clarify, there is a js that is clearing the title tag after the page loads. With js disabled the title tag is fine. But with js the title tag is erased after page load.

Is there a way to search through js that has been run to see what is rewriting the title tag? That way I can track down the source and fix it.

I tried using the break ability on the console but it does not work because the title is being changed on page load. Any idea how to break on an element change on a page load? This is really annoying.

Comment: by title you mean that your website title is now an URL? Also, have you tried moving your `<title>` directly to the top of your `<header>`?

Comment: Are you using domain forwarding by any chance?

Comment: I mean the title tag. With js disabled title appears normally and does not get erased. What is the best way to track down which js is doing it?

Answer (score 1):

After validating you website, it says that you have a 500 internal server error at

https://fyxtrpg.com/xmlrpc.php

and since that file is being called before the `<title>` tag, I think you are seeing the error output. [image: internal server error]

You should check the xmlrpc.php file error origin, many possible causes for this error: chmod, server configuration, etc

Answer (score 0):

You have WordPress SEO installed. From the plugin settings page you can locate to `Titles and Metas` and check the `Enable force rewrite titles`.

Comment: I use Yoast SEO and do not see a force rewrite titles option. It is definitely a js issue. Title tag appears and works normally with js disabled.

Comment: I disabled Yoast SEO all together and it is still happening. Is there a way to search through the js that is loaded for title tag manipulation?